# how to rotate 3D image in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, octave

Do we have a facility to rotate the image, using mouse, to see different views in gnuplot.
I wish gnuplot had similar facility to rotate the image as MATLAB has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my version it just works.

```
Version 4.4 patchlevel 0
last modified March 2010
```

[image]

Comment: you mean to say, you can rotate the image by clicking on the image area and moving the mouse while left button is pressed?

Comment: Also your plot has top and bottom panes, which i am not able to get. I am using command line to plot the image and the image opens up in a simple x11 viewer with no top and bottom panes.

Comment: One can indeed rotate the image with the mouse. I'm using debian 6. Maybe you'll have to compile a new version for your system, check the configure options. It's probably GTK.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to change the terminal for gnuplot.
The window with the nice toolbar is generated by the "wxt" terminal.

```
gnuplot> set term wxt
```

Use 'set term' without parameters to show a list of available terminals.

```
gnuplot> set term
```